# How do I pass a parameter as an input into another function?

Tags: linux, bash

So I have two functions in my Bash Script but I am not too sure how to call another function within a function AND inject an input so it will complete an action from that specific function.

```
function DoingSomething {
    read -r input
    if [ "$input" == '1' ]; then
    #do this action

    elif ["$input" == '2' ]; then
    #do this other action
    else
    echo -e "Enter something correct!"
    fi
}


function DoingThat {
    if [ $param -gt 50 ];
    then `DoingSomething`
#Essentially I want this function to input '2' into DoingSomething when its called

    else
    echo -e "You are okay!"
    fi
}
```

Any help is appreciated! :)

I have tried to use the && command.

```
then `DoingSomething` && "2"
```

Comment: In bash, you can use this construct: `DoingSomething <<< "2"`, if `DoingSomething` is supposed to read from `stdin`.

Comment: Note that `["$input"` is buggy -- the space after the `[` is mandatory. And `==` should be `=` inside `[` for compliance with the standard documented at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html. And `function funcname {` is a throwback to the early 80s -- the standard way to define a function in modern / post-1991 shells is `funcname() {`, see the last table in https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete. And it should be `[ "$param" -gt 50 ]`, _with the quotes_.

Comment: And `echo -e` is not just nonportable but unreliable; even if your shell is bash, it can be configured to print `-e` on output (if in POSIX mode with the `xpg_echo` flag enabled -- both those flags can be configured via environment variables or at compile time).

Comment: Also, using backticks like: ```then `DoingSomething` ``` tells bash to run `DoingSomething`, capture its output, and *run that output as another command*. I'm pretty sure you want the output to be printed, not executed, so remove those backticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requiring interactive input is a poor design choice. Make the function read an argument instead.

```
function DoingSomething {
    local input=$1
    if [ "$input" = '1' ]; then    # only one = for portability
        # do this action
    elif [ "$input" = '2' ]; then  # need space after [
        # do this other action
    else
        # don't use echo -e; print error messages to stderr
        echo "DoingSomething: Enter something correct!" >&2
    fi
}
```

You might want to refactor this into a `case` statement, and use more mnemonic values than small integers.

```
function DoingSomething {
    case $1 in 
      'frobnicate')
        # do this action;; 
      'fuss')
        # do this other action;;
      *)
        echo "DoingSomething: Enter something correct!" >&2;;
    esac
}
```

If you want interactive user I/O, you can put that in the calling function.

```
read -p "what shall we do?" action
DoingSomething "$action"
```

... but generally, reading command-line arguments is a much better design choice for both usability and reusability.

Of course, if you are hellbent on keeping the design, the solution is

```
echo 2 | DoingSomething
```

or (Bash-only "here string" syntax)

```
DoingSomething <<<2
```

Answer (score 2):

`read -r reply` implies you want to either a) read from stdin or b) prompt the user for input.  For the former a couple approaches come to mind:

```
echo 2 | DoingSomething

# or

DoingSomething <<< 2
```

An alternative would see the `2` passed as a command line argument to the function, eg:

```
DoingSomething 2
```

If you (really) want to support this type of variability you need to add some logic to the function, eg:

```
DoingSomething() {

    if [[ -n "$1" ]]                     # if a non-blank value has been passed on the command line then ...
    then
        reply="$1"                       # store said value
    else
        read -r -p "prompt: " reply      # else read from stdin
    fi
    echo "reply: $reply"
}
```

Taking for a test drive:

```
$ echo 3 | DoingSomething                # stdin via pipe
reply: 3

$ DoingSomething <<< "3"                  # stdin via here-string
reply: 3

$ DoingSomething                         # stdin from user
prompt: 7                                # function displays "prompt: "; user enters "7"
reply: 7

$ DoingSomething 27                      # command line arg
reply: 27
```